# awk not getting correct comparison result on data bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, bc

I have a file file.txt,

```
ch.qos.logback:logback-classic 1.2.0
ch.qos.logback:logback-core 1.2.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.10.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.6.7
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.6.7
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.7.9
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.8.11
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.8.11
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.8.9
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.9.10
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.9.10
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.9.10
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.9.5
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.9.7
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.9.8
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.9.9
com.h2database:h2 2.0.206
com.h2database:h2 2.1.210
com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream 1.4.11
com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream 1.4.16
commons-collections:commons-collections 3.2.2
commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload 1.3.3
handlebars 4.3.0
handlebars 4.7.7
io.dropwizard:dropwizard-validation 1.3.21
io.netty:netty-all 4.1.44
io.netty:netty-codec 4.1.66
io.netty:netty-codec-http 4.1.44
io.vertx:vertx-web 3.5.4
net.minidev:json-smart 2.4.1
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common 0.23.4
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core 2.3.1
org.apache.shiro:shiro-core 1.7.1
org.apache.shiro:shiro-web 1.5.2
org.apache.shiro:shiro-web 1.5.3
org.apache.shiro:shiro-web 1.7.1
org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core 7.0.89
org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core 9.0.31
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http 9.2.25
org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core 3.3.2
org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons 1.13.11
org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2 2.3.3
org.springframework:spring-web 5.3.0
```

I want to get the unique package names with the highest version mentioned
in the file.

I tried awk as below but the result is not as expected,

```
cat file.txt | awk '$2 > a[$1]{a[$1] = $2} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}'

RESULT:
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http 9.2.25
io.netty:netty-codec 4.1.66
com.h2database:h2 2.1.210
org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core 3.3.2
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core 2.3.1
io.vertx:vertx-web 3.5.4
handlebars 4.7.7
com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream 1.4.16
ch.qos.logback:logback-core 1.2.0
net.minidev:json-smart 2.4.1
org.apache.shiro:shiro-core 1.7.1
commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload 1.3.3
org.springframework:spring-web 5.3.0
commons-collections:commons-collections 3.2.2
org.apache.shiro:shiro-web 1.7.1
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.9.9
io.netty:netty-all 4.1.44
org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2 2.3.3
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common 0.23.4
io.dropwizard:dropwizard-validation 1.3.21
org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core 9.0.31
org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons 1.13.11
ch.qos.logback:logback-classic 1.2.0
io.netty:netty-codec-http 4.1.44
```

But the result is not correct, like 2.9.0, 2.10.0 here it takes 2.9 as greater which is not expected.

Could you please help.

Comment: Awk only knows string comparison and numeric comparison. Version comparison is not part of its knowledge. Eg 0.2.3 and 0.2.23 are compared as strings and therefore 0.2.23 < 0.2.3

Comment: Are you processing the file on Linux?

Answer (score 4):

The main problem with your script was `$2 > a[$1]` is doing a **string** (i.e. alphabetic, character by character) comparison instead of a **version** (i.e. numeric, dot-separated number by dot-separated number) comparison and so `10` comes before `9` since the first chars compared are `1` vs `9` and `1` is less than `9`.

awk doesn't have a notion of "versions" so you'd have to code a version-comparison yourself in awk, but GNU sort has it built in so - using GNU sort for `-V`, "version sort":

```
$ sort -k2,2Vr file | awk '!seen[$1]++'
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http 9.2.25
org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core 9.0.31
org.springframework:spring-web 5.3.0
handlebars 4.7.7
io.netty:netty-codec 4.1.66
io.netty:netty-all 4.1.44
io.netty:netty-codec-http 4.1.44
io.vertx:vertx-web 3.5.4
org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core 3.3.2
commons-collections:commons-collections 3.2.2
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.10.0
net.minidev:json-smart 2.4.1
org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2 2.3.3
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core 2.3.1
com.h2database:h2 2.1.210
org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons 1.13.11
org.apache.shiro:shiro-core 1.7.1
org.apache.shiro:shiro-web 1.7.1
com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream 1.4.16
io.dropwizard:dropwizard-validation 1.3.21
commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload 1.3.3
ch.qos.logback:logback-classic 1.2.0
ch.qos.logback:logback-core 1.2.0
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common 0.23.4
```

or if you care about the output being sorted alphabetically too you can do either of these (the former holds every unique `$1` in memory in the awk script while the latter holds just 2 $1 values at a time in memory in the awk script):

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2Vr file | awk '!seen[$1]++'
sort -k1,1 -k2,2Vr file | awk '$1!=prev{print; prev=$1}'
```

For example:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2,2Vr file | awk '!seen[$1]++'
ch.qos.logback:logback-classic 1.2.0
ch.qos.logback:logback-core 1.2.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.10.0
com.h2database:h2 2.1.210
com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream 1.4.16
commons-collections:commons-collections 3.2.2
commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload 1.3.3
handlebars 4.7.7
io.dropwizard:dropwizard-validation 1.3.21
io.netty:netty-all 4.1.44
io.netty:netty-codec 4.1.66
io.netty:netty-codec-http 4.1.44
io.vertx:vertx-web 3.5.4
net.minidev:json-smart 2.4.1
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common 0.23.4
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core 2.3.1
org.apache.shiro:shiro-core 1.7.1
org.apache.shiro:shiro-web 1.7.1
org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core 9.0.31
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http 9.2.25
org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core 3.3.2
org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons 1.13.11
org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2 2.3.3
org.springframework:spring-web 5.3.0
```

Comment: Hi Ed, a shorter version for `awk '$1!=prev{print; prev=$1}'` might be `awk '$1!=prev;{prev=$1}'`. The operation count is a bit more expensive thought.

Comment: And the very questionable single statement version might be: `awk 'prev!=(prev=$1)' `. But I wonder if this is undefined behaviour (it works on GNU awk 4.2.1).

Comment: @kvantour Beats me, I'm surprised it works in gawk. If brevity was really a goal I'd just use a shorter variable name like `p` instead of `prev`, i.e. `awk '$1!=p{print; p=$1}'`, so as to not sacrifice any performance and keep relatively decent clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it with `perl` instead of `awk`, which has native version types that can be compared sensibly:

```sh
$ perl -Mversion -lane '
my $v = version->parse("v$F[1]");
$packages{$F[0]} = $v if $v > $packages{$F[0]};
END {
  foreach my $p (sort keys %packages) {
    print $p, "\t", substr($packages{$p}, 1)
  }
}' input.txt
ch.qos.logback:logback-classic  1.2.0
ch.qos.logback:logback-core 1.2.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind 2.10.0
com.h2database:h2   2.1.210
com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream    1.4.16
commons-collections:commons-collections 3.2.2
commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload   1.3.3
handlebars  4.7.7
io.dropwizard:dropwizard-validation 1.3.21
io.netty:netty-all  4.1.44
io.netty:netty-codec    4.1.66
io.netty:netty-codec-http   4.1.44
io.vertx:vertx-web  3.5.4
net.minidev:json-smart  2.4.1
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common 0.23.4
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core 2.3.1
org.apache.shiro:shiro-core 1.7.1
org.apache.shiro:shiro-web  1.7.1
org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core   9.0.31
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http    9.2.25
org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core    3.3.2
org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons    1.13.11
org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2   2.3.3
org.springframework:spring-web  5.3.0
```